# How to update a dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
>>> {'a':3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1}
```

How can I update it to,

```
>>> updateDict({'a':3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1}, 
                   milk),
```

such that the output is

```
{'a':3, 'i': 0, 'k': 0, 'm': 0, 'l': 0, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1}
```

?

Comment: So you want to know how you can input a string and all keys with letters from the string have their values updated to 0?

Comment: newDict = Dict.copy()
 updateDict = newDict(Dict,word)
 return updateDict

Answer (score 3):

To reset the keys in `'milk'` to 0:

```
In [14]: d = {'a':3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1 } 

In [15]: d.update(dict.fromkeys(list('milk'), 0))

In [16]: d
Out[16]: {'a': 3, 'i': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1}
```

---

To decrement the keys in `'milk'` by 1, you could use a loop, as in [mitchelllc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167568/190597). Or, if you are willing to eliminate keys with values of 0, you could use a collections.Counter like this:

```
import collections

d = collections.Counter({'a':3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1 })

m = collections.Counter(list('milk'))

print(d - m)
```

yields

```
Counter({'a': 3, 'p': 1, 'u': 1, 'n': 1})
```

Comment: `list` is redundant here.

Comment: True, but since the OP's actual dict could have multi-character keys, the list form may be of more practical value.

Comment: `list` doesn't change the result here in any way.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> dict = {'a':3, 'i': 0, 'k': 0, 'm': 0, 'l': 0, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1}
>>> for s in 'milk':
>>>    if s in dict:
>>>        dict[s] -= 1
```

If you want to set 'milk' to zero in the dict, see @unutbu's answer.

Answer (score 0):

For each character in the string get the corresponding value from the dictionary, decrement the value, and reinsert it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = 'milk'
d = {'a':3, 'i': 1, 'k': 1, 'm': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1, 'p': 1, 'u': 1 }
for letter in s:
     if letter in d:
         d[letter] = 0
```